# Problema al exportar una función JS

Tags: javascript, nodejs, funciones, npm

Estoy tratando de resolver este ejercicio de ver si un año es bisiesto o no, de la página [Exercism](https://exercism.io) pero no al ejecutar el test me arroja esto,

*Error:*

[image: Error 3]

**Solución**

Archivo leap.js

```
export function isLeap (year) {
    if (year % 4 != 0) {
        return false
    } else if (year % 100 == 0 && year % 400 != 0) {
        return false
    }else if (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) {
        return true
    } else if (year % 400 == 0) {
        return true
    }
}
```

Archivo leap.spec.js

```
import { isLeap } from './leap.js';
describe('A leap year', () => {
  test('year not divisible by 4: common year', () => {
    expect(isLeap(2015)).toBeFalsy();
  });
  test('year divisible by 4, not divisible by 100: leap year', () => {
    expect(isLeap(2016)).toBeTruthy();
  });
  test('year divisible by 100, not divisible by 400: common year', () => {
    expect(isLeap(2100)).toBeFalsy();
  });
  test('year divisible by 400: leap year', () => {
    expect(isLeap(2000)).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: Si agregas el código a la página en lugar de imágenes te podrían ayudar de mejor manera.

Comment: Que valor tiene year?

Comment: @DavidLeonardoMolinaRuizDav el problema no es el valor, es que no se está importando la función, el valor de year sale en la segunda imagen

Comment: ¿Podrías sustituir las imágenes por texto real? Es más cómodo para todos

Comment: Me gusto esa pagina amigo, te pone a pensar, muy util cuando estas fuera de forma al codificar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Agrega la palabra export a la declaración de la función:

```
export function isLeap(year) {
```